# text is not appearing at cursor in bash, can I reset it somehow?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

This happens sometimes if the VM bumps up against upper limits of memory and has to hit swap heavily for extended periods (a few minutes or more). When this happens and I type `asdf` at the prompt it looks like:

```
$ No command 'asdf' found, did you mean:
 Command 'asdfg' from package 'aoeui' (universe)
 Command 'sadf' from package 'sysstat' (main)
 Command 'sdf' from package 'sdf' (universe)
asdf: command not found

$
```

Note that `asdf` isn't showing up after `$`.

The obvious answer is to just kill the tab and start a new one. Still, I have to wonder if there's a way to reset a bash terminal that is misbehaving like this. I tried `bash` and it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can reset it, using the `reset` command.

Comment: oh lord, I should have known to at least try that...

Comment: Don't worry, took me years to figure that one out. :)

Comment: @Jord I'm on it, I like to let the question sit for a few days in case a better answer shows up.

Comment: @jcollum, we're going to reach 500 days in a month. Just saying... ;)

Comment: done -- i would have gotten to it, in a while, maybe a long while